# Users friends link not working - displaying 404 error

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm in the process of creating a website that allows people to do quizzes about different topics and for the quizzes, I have a button called `Ask A Friend`. At the moment, with the code I have, it doesn't display anything to press and when I click on the area where the mouse changes to a pointer, I get shown a `404 error`. What I want to happen is, is a user clicks on the button, it directs them to their own friends list.

The code that I have is:

```
<div class="AskAFriend">
    <div class="askafriend">
        <a href="<?php global $current_user; echo home_url() . '/members/' . $current_user->user_login . '/friends/'; ?>">
            <input class="AskAFriend_button" name="askafriend" type="button" value="Ask A Friend For Help" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
&nbsp;
```

When I had it with an empty `<a>` tag, it displayed a button as I wanted, but with the code I have now, no button gets displaed and I get directed to a page that has a `404 error` on.

I believe that it's the `<a>` tag that's causing the trouble.

Comment: 404 means not found, so the url just does not exist on your site

Comment: @FMashiro How would I do change it so it displays each individual users' own friends list?

Comment: Where do you want to display it? If it's a page, just have a url that opens a page in which you find the current user and select his or her friends

Comment: @FMashiro I want the button to be displayed on the quizzes page, so that if a user is stuck, it opens up a new page that is their friends list. But the site I'm creating will have multiple users which will have access to the button and they'll need to get directed to their own friends, not just one persons

Answer (score 0):

Alright,  so I'm guessing the user is logged in, and that you save the user's ID in the session. What you can do is make a page like friends.php, on there using PHP you get the user ID from the session variable, once you have that, query for all the friends of that user. This way, you have one page that will be used by all the different users.

Comment: I already have two `friends.php` files, one being for friend requests, and the other for displaying friends

Comment: That isn't a problem,  but you should just make a new one called friendlist.php or something that shows the list

Comment: When I click on the `My Friends` icon in the menu, it works and does display all the friends any given user has, as I've made two accounts with different friends and it does work; but how would I link the friends list to the button?

Comment: You put the right url in the href of the anchor link

Answer (score 0):

If you are using buddypress plugin, then may be it has some conflict with other plugin. It happened with me. In my case buddypress plugin conflict with upme plugin, you have to check it first.

Comment: Thanks for the relpy

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain . '/friends/'; ?>">
```